# Same NextJs page layout but display different data

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a nextjs app with two pages, they have same design but both display different data, what is the best way to implement this idea with keeping the url path unique for each page.

Comment: Use dynamic paths. `pages/[unique-slug].js`. Depending on the value of `unique-slug`, you may then display relevant data. [Docs for your reference](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes)

Comment: Thank you very much, Will i face any problems when directly create this file at pages dir, or should i make another directory for it ?

Comment: depends on how you want to structure things. I'd recommend `pages/[unique-slug]/index.js` so that if you want to introduce a new path under `unique-slug/some-path`, it's as simple as creating `pages/[unique-slug]/some-path.js` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after asking some friends about this issue the best answer i got (from my prospective) is to separate the repeated code at the two pages into a new directory which I named `shared` and a new component that has only one job to display the data passed to it from both pages.